# Feasibiliy of KERS for bicycles (editor: likely Kinetic Energy Recovery System)

Tags: design, hypothetical

[image]

I want to know more about KERS for bicycles... 
I have a question. What will happen if we attach the flywheel on front wheel? Does it make any difference? 
Please reply me.. I preparing this as my minor project of M.E 6th sem... Please provide some guidence...

Comment: I removed the "new bike assembly" tag and added "design" and "hypothetical."

Comment: See this [answer by RoboKaren](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/31128/8273), and this [answer by Móż](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/25031/8273). Mike Baranczak also links to [Bike with Regenerative Braking](http://gizmodo.com/5022587/panasonic-makes-electric-bike-with-regenerative-braking). None of these have anything to do with flywheels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I take it KERS is *"Kinetic Energy Recovery System"* which takes energy from your momentum and stores it temporarily, also offering a braking effect.  With the intention to use this stored energy for subsequent acceleration.

A spinning flywheel on the front wheel may have significant [precession effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession) when spun up.   If the rider tries to turn left or right, and the flywheel is co-planar with the rim, then the wheel will experience a rotational force around the long axis of the bike.

In short the front wheel will try and lie on its side.

This would prove dangerous if unexpected by the rider, and the scale of the force would vary with how much rotational energy the flywheel has stored.

A flywheel on the back wheel would experience similar forces on cornering, but the back wheel follows the turn rather than being moved to create the turn.

Downsides to a rear KERS, the wheel is already busy with drive, and often has disk brakes too.  Adding something inside the rear wheel will increase the weight where we don't want it, and rear wheel braking is the least useful sort of braking.

So, added weight, added complexity, added adrenaline when the bike kicks sideways, and minimal benefit.

Comment: Not trying to be completely negative - a KERS might be brilliant on a three wheel bike like a tricycle/recumbent, or a quad.   A Postie / Mail deliverer might benefit from a cargo bike with the ability to help get from 0 to something every time they get going.

Comment: A KERS would also be EXCELLENT on a rubbish truck, because they're consistently starting and stopping at each bin.   Or a milk float, if you still have them.

Comment: Then what would i should do to balance the flywheel nd rotation of the bicycle.. As adjusting the flywheel is itself very hard..

Comment: You should also do a back of the envelope calculation on how much energy you can recover with KERS. If you google search for "E-bike regenerative braking" or something, you'll find people's arguments on [how much energy you'd recover](http://www.ecospeed.com/regenbraking.pdf). The general upshot is that at best, the system will get you 5-10% of what you put in, but in a decent number of cases may cost you more energy.

Comment: @Criggie Milk floats in the UK were traditionally electric, so regenerative braking would be very natural and not involve much extra equipment.

Comment: I'd think that an electrical KERS system wouldn't suffer from the precession effects.  Whether or not that would be practical, I don't know; I suspect the added weight would overwhelm the benefit of the recovered energy for a human-powered bike.  Building one would be an interesting project though!  KERS for an e-bike might be practical though...

Comment: @PankajNegi maybe two opposing flywheels that spin in opposite directions ?  Adds to the weight though.

Comment: @Criggie That solves the precession problem, at the cost of extra gearing and bearing loads. As a kid I designed a spring-based KERS, but there was always the question *what happens in a crash*? We have a similar problem with all these schemes. But I think a [Supercapacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor) is worth considering.

Comment: I was gonna make this as my project.. So can u guyz suggest me something better nd affordable so that i could make a good and useful project to everyone normal people.... What new can i make in ordinary bicycles?

Comment: @PankajNegi All this is part of your design discovery phase, so document it.  Are you looking for something to use a KERS on something, or something you can add to a bike to make it better?

Comment: @criggie My group nd me are willing to use KERS on bicycle if it is suitable.. If not than can u suggest me something else that could do good...?

Comment: What will happen if we reduces flywheel's radius in KERS designing..? Will it effect its power storing capacity??

Comment: Answer to my question guyz

Comment: @PankajNegi you should try asking this on physics.stackexchange.com and see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

As implemented by Audi, the trick isn't to depend on mass so much as speed. Both are input variables. A faster flywheel requires better bearings so the cost goes up. Also, I would expect precession to remain a factor, but if it's in near the center-of-rotation of the bicycle, then the effect would more predictable at least no?

Comment: Does Audi manufacture bikes now??

Comment: @ojs to my surprise, yes   https://www.audi-technology-portal.de/en/mobility-for-the-future/audi-future-lab-mobility_en/audi-e-bike-woerthersee_en   But they don't have KERS - likely that part comes from the Audi F1 team's efforts to include KERS in their race cars where higher speeds would be more common.

Comment: This appears to be more of a response to the existing answer than a direct answer to the question.  "I would expect precession to remain a factor" makes little sense in the context of the question, which doesn't mention precession.  Please write answers that stand on their own and don't require incorporation of another post to answer the question.